# Round to nearest even integer with condition applied using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to round the values to the nearest even number - however if value is 0.5 ; round this to the number 2.

**Data**

```
ID  Q121 Q221 Q321 Q421 Q122 
AA  0.5  0.5  6.6  11.4 6.8
BB  8.5  6.5  3.1  5.3  7.2
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Q121 Q221 Q321 Q421 Q122 
AA  2.0  2.0  6.0  12   6.0  
BB  8.0  6.0  4.0  6.0  8.0
```

**Doing**

```
df.iloc[:,1:].astype(float).div(2).round()
```

However, this only rounds the numbers to nearest even without the condition applied. I am still researching, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Use `np.where` to handle `0.5` specially.

Comment: ok looking this up and will apply - thank you

Comment: added an answer, does it help? @Lynn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# 0.5 being a special case, where it need to be made into 2
# check if value is zero when made into int, if so, make it 1

df.iloc[:,1:]=np.where(df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int)==0,
                       1, 
                       df.iloc[:,1:])

# if int value is odd, add 1 to it, else leave it as is
df.iloc[:,1:]=np.where(df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int)%2==1,
                       df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int) +1, 
                       df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int))
 
df
```

```
    ID  Q121    Q221    Q321    Q421    Q122
0   AA     2       2       6      12       6
1   BB     8       6       4       6       8
```

if 0.5 should be made to zero then

```
df.iloc[:,1:]=np.where(df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int)%2==1,
                       df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int) +1, 
                       df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int))
```

```
    ID  Q121    Q221    Q321    Q421    Q122
0   AA     0       0       6      12       6
1   BB     8       6       4       6       8
```

Comment: thank you @Naveed - I will try- I understand the logic thank you

Comment: Hi @Naveed - if less than 0.5, I wish for the result to be 0. Could I just adjust this: 
df.iloc[:,1:]=np.where(df.iloc[:,1:].astype(int)==0, 1,    df.iloc[:,1:])

Comment: then you won't need the first np.where  I tried to match your expected result

Comment: @Lynn, solution updated

Comment: oh @Naveed - first solution is great- I am wondering if the value is less than 0.5; would I add comparison operator <0.5 then = 0  but if 0.5 please round to 2

Comment: both solutions are in the answer

Answer (score 1):

edited:

```
# round as the expected result shows
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(lambda   x:  int(x) if x > .5 else 1)
# making it even
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(lambda x: x if x%2==0 else x+1)
```

|  | ID | Q121 | Q221 | Q321 | Q421 | Q122 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AA | 2 | 2 | 6 | 12 | 6 |
| 1 | BB | 8 | 6 | 4 | 6 | 8 |

Comment: thank you - what in the code specifies if it is above 0.5? is it this piece? x%2==0

Comment: `ROUND_HALF_UP`

Comment: @MAFiA303, your result dont' match the expected result

Comment: i fixed it accordingly