# Output sum rounded to the nearest even number using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to take the sum of each row and round this value to the closest even number.

**Data**

```
id  type    Q1 22   Q2 22   Q3 22   Q4 22  
AA  hi      0.2     0.8     0.3     2.1      
AA  hello   0.2     0.7     0.3     1.7     
AA  ok      2       0.1     0       0.1
```

**Desired**

```
id  type    Q1 22   Q2 22   Q3 22   Q4 22  rounded_nearest_sum
AA  hi      0.2     0.8     0.3     2.1    4
AA  hello   0.2     0.7     0.3     1.7    2
AA  ok      2       0.1     0       0.1    2
```

**Doing**

```
df.loc[:,'rounded_nearest_sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

I realize I have to incorporate i+i.mod(2) into this script, however I am not sure how to incorporate. Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: Some possible solutions here: [Round to nearest even integer with condition applied using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74045421/13843268)

Comment: thank you @sj95126 I will investigate

Comment: There's a fair bit of over-complication going on, when your original idea of incorporating `i+i.mod(2)` into the script was correct. I've shown how to do that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# filter columns that has 'Q' in their name and sum along the rows (across columns)
df['rounded_sum']=df.filter(like='Q').sum(axis=1)

# using np.where, check if integer part is even or odd
# if odd, add 1 else, keep the integer as is
df['rounded_sum']=np.where(df['rounded_sum'].astype(int)%2==1,
                           df['rounded_sum'].astype(int) +1, 
                           df['rounded_sum'].astype(int))
df
```

```
    id  type    Q1 22   Q2 22   Q3 22   Q4 22   rounded_sum
0   AA  hi        0.2     0.8     0.3     2.1      4
1   AA  hello     0.2     0.7     0.3     1.7      2
2   AA  ok        2.0     0.1     0.0     0.1      2
```

Comment: Ok let me check thank you @Naveed

Answer (score 2):

You can divide by 2, round, then multiply by 2. To take the row sums, use `sum(numeric_only=True)` to exclude non-numeric values.

```
import pandas as pd

k = ['id', 'type',  'Q1 22',   'Q2 22',   'Q3 22',   'Q4 22']
d = [
    ['AA','hi',   0.2, 0.8, 0.3  ,2.1],
    ['AA','hello',0.2, 0.7, 0.3  ,1.7],
    ['AA','ok',   2  , 0.1, 0    ,0.1],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=k).set_index('id')

df['rounded_nearest_sum'] = df.sum(axis=1, numeric_only=True).divide(2).round().multiply(2).astype(int)
```

This will give you the data frame:

```
     type  Q1 22  Q2 22  Q3 22  Q4 22  rounded_nearest_sum
id                                                        
AA     hi    0.2    0.8    0.3    2.1                    4
AA  hello    0.2    0.7    0.3    1.7                    2
AA     ok    2.0    0.1    0.0    0.1                    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter quaters, add and conditionally format. List comprehensionnis always your friend. Neater and one liner

`[int(np.ceil(y)) if np.floor(y) % 2 != 0 else int(np.floor(y)) for y in list(df.filter(regex='Q', axis=1).sum(1))]`

Comment: It's not clear that this will round to the closest **even** number.

Comment: Ok, let's try. Noted `[int(np.ceil(y)) if np.floor(y) % 2 != 0 else int(np.floor(y)) for y in list(df.filter(regex='Q', axis=1).sum(1))]`

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
   id   type  Q1 22  Q2 22  Q3 22  Q4 22
0  AA     hi    0.2    0.8    0.3    2.1
1  AA  hello    0.2    0.7    0.3    1.7
2  AA     ok    2.0    0.1    0.0    0.1
```

Doing:

```
# These look like they would work as an index:
df = df.set_index(['id', 'type'])

# Now, we'll get your initial result.
res = df.sum(1).astype(int)

# Modified to be even, we'll add one to the odds.
df['rounded_sum'] = res.mod(2).add(res)
# This is done by adding the mod 2 of res to itself.

print(df)
```

One-Liner Version:

```
df = (df.set_index(['id', 'type'])
        .assign(rounded_sum=lambda x: (res := x.sum(1).astype(int)).mod(2).add(res)))
```

Output:

```
          Q1 22  Q2 22  Q3 22  Q4 22  rounded_sum
id type
AA hi       0.2    0.8    0.3    2.1            4
   hello    0.2    0.7    0.3    1.7            2
   ok       2.0    0.1    0.0    0.1            2
```

Comment: Always find all the reasons possible to avoid lambda. It's very slow

Comment: lol, then you don't understand them. A `lambda` in an `assign` is nothing like a `lambda` in an `apply`. It'll be just as fast, if not faster here. @wwnde